# struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 2 on the second input of the program

Tags: python, struct, compiler-errors

I am writing a program for the communication between two bots using Python, project Skynet if anyone knows about it. While writing, i got this problem

```
File "C:\Users\achau\Desktop\Uni\Fundamental of Sec\Project\part1\skynet_intro\lib\comms.py", line 87, in recv
    unpacked_contents = struct.unpack('H', pkt_len_packed)
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 2
```

The weird thing is the code always work on the first time, but the second time i enter a message, it become like that. Does anyone have any idea? This is that line of code

```
  def recv(self):
        # Decode the data's length from an unsigned two byte int ('H')
        pkt_len_packed = self.conn.recv(struct.calcsize('H'))
        unpacked_contents = struct.unpack('H', pkt_len_packed)
        pkt_len = unpacked_contents[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `conn` is a socket.  `socket.recv(n)` returns maximum of n bytes but does not guarantee there are n bytes. Just a guess, but it may be that your recv just returns one byte.

Check what is the length of `pkt_len_packed` before calling `struct.unpack()` on it. It will probably be just one.

One of the very typical socket programming mistakes is the assumption that sockets deliver messages. They do not, they deliver data and are completely agnostic to its format, length, contents and other such things. If and when you are receiving messages, you need to parse the messages from data stream.  If you intend to send 2 bytes, it is entirely possible that only one has been transmitted when you call recv() and you would receive just that. Then you would need to store what you just received and keep receiving until you have everything you need.   If your socket already contains several messages and you call recv with a length greater than the length of the message first in queue, you will receive data from one or more consecutive messages as well. If you now discard this data, you lost messages or a part of a message, or both.

Another possibility is that you transmit N characters, but there is a trailing newline or another terminator character. For example, if you have built a messaging protocol that transmits first the length of data and then the actual message, but you write to the socket the length and the message string with a trailing character, then your receiver would work fine with your first message. It would receive the length, call `recv()` on that length, and you would think everything is fine. But there is still one byte more to be read from the socket (newline?, terminating zero?), and when you now try to call `recv()` again to get the two bytes long message length of your second message, you actually just received the trailing terminator character you should have read as a part of the first message, or not sent at all. This is just speculation but these mistakes are incredibly common.

This is why you should either use a higher level interface that operates on messages (ZeroMQ would do that), or separate socket operations from message processing, and validate everything you receive from the socket before doing anything to it, to ensure you have all the data you need. You also need to know what you actually write to the socket and ensure you receive all invisible characters you sent as well. And if you received more than you were expecting to receive, you need to keep the remainder and keep adding up to it until a complete message is present.